# How to find index of element in list that starts with a given string

Tags: python, string, time-complexity

For example if I have list of strings and given string

```
list=['aab','bab','ccab','dab']
s='da'
```

and if I want to find index of element that starts with `s` I know I can do this like this

```
i=0
for l in list :
    if l[0:len(s)]==s:
        print(i)
        break
    i+=1
```

but time complexity for this is *O(n)* .Question is, can this be done in *O(1)*, because the only way I know is using hash function, but I'm not sure I can use hash function in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get O(1) is to sacrifice space. Create a dictionary with all possible queries as keys and the results as values.

For example:

```
lookup = {
    "a": {0},
    "b": {1},
    "c": {2},
    "d": {3},
    "aa": {0},
    "ba": {1},
    "ca": {2},
    "da": {3},
    # etc
}
```

Comment: Can I get the job done with queries from list that I put in question? Because in my case I can't do all possible queries, list where I want to find answer to my question is much much bigger

Comment: Since your requirement is to have O(1) lookup, then no. You'll need to precalculate all possible answers and cache it. Then use it to do your lookups.